Remove Query String from Redirected URL $request_uri?
I am new to Nginx and I'm facing an issue with my Nginx configuration. I have set up a list of redirects using the map directive ($request_uri) as shown below:
map $request_uri $staticRequestRedirect {
    /agb.php?s=agb&agb=1 /company/agb/;
    /news/prices-again-high-?id=101451 /news;
}


The redirect itself works, but the problem is that the query string from the original request is still appended to the redirected URL.
For example, the URL /agb.php?s=agb&agb=1 gets redirected to /company/agb/?s=agb&agb=1, but I want it to be /company/agb/ without the query string. I have many different query strings with different names. I have tried with rewrite but without success.
In my configuration, I use the following if block to handle the redirection:
if ($staticRequestRedirect != "") {
    return 301 $scheme://www.${DOMAIN}$staticRequestRedirect$is_args$args;
}

Is there any way to remove the query string using $request_uri?
